# Remove everything up to and including a certain character pattern in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to extract numbers from this text in Notepad++:

```
Line  15: 68.68259216
Line  22: 46.4267076
Line  29: 158.30325204
```

In other words, I need everything up to and including ": " removed.

TIA

Comment: try this `Line(.*)\:`

Answer (score 0):

Use regex https://regex101.com/r/CCVf6M/1 - this is example with your data
or open replace ctrl+ H turn on regex
if search, paste: `Line  \d+:` 
and in replace with put nothing and click replace all